# What does phrase in Psalm 139:9 "the wings of the dawn/the wings of the morning" mean?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible, layers-of-meaning, metaphor

I might be asking the obvious.
What does phrase in Psalm 139:9 "the wings of the dawn/the wings of the morning" mean?

> (Psalm 139:7-10) (NASB1995)
>
> 7 Where can I go from Your Spirit? Or where can I flee from Your
> presence? 8 If I ascend to heaven, You are there; If I make my bed in
> Sheol, behold, You are there.
> **9 If I take the wings of the dawn,** If I dwell in the remotest part of the sea, 10 Even there Your hand will lead me, And Your right hand
> will lay hold of me.

> Psalm 139:7-10 (NKJV)
>
> 7 Where can I go from Your Spirit? Or where can I flee from Your
> presence? 8 If I ascend into heaven, You are there; If I make my bed
> in [a]hell, behold, You are there.
> **9 If I take the wings of the morning,** And dwell in the uttermost parts of the sea, 10 Even there Your hand shall lead me, And Your
> right hand shall hold me.

> 139:7-10 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 7 אָ֭נָ֥ה אֵלֵ֣ךְ מֵרוּחֶ֑ךָ
> וְ֝אָ֗נָה מִפָּנֶ֥יךָ אֶבְרָֽח׃
>
> 8 אִם־אֶסַּ֣ק שָׁ֭מַיִם שָׁ֣ם אָ֑תָּה וְאַצִּ֖יעָה שְּׁא֣וֹל
> הִנֶּֽךָּ׃
>
> 9 אֶשָּׂ֥א כַנְפֵי־שָׁ֑חַר אֶ֝שְׁכְּנָ֗ה בְּאַחֲרִ֥ית יָֽם׃
>
> 10 גַּם־שָׁ֭ם יָדְךָ֣ תַנְחֵ֑נִי וְֽתֹאחֲזֵ֥נִי יְמִינֶֽךָ׃

Answer (score 5):

Just referencing some commentaries in https://www.biblestudytools.com/psalms/139-9.html

> Psalms 139:9
> John Gill's Exposition of the Bible
>
> [If] I take the wings of the morning And fly as swift as the morning
> light to the east, to the **extremity of it,** as Ben Melech; as far
> as he could go that way, as swiftly as the wings of the morning could
> carry him thither; so the morning is represented by the Heathens as
> having wings F6; or as the rays of the rising sun, called wings for
> the swiftness of them, ( Malachi 4:2 ) ;
>
> [and] dwell in the uttermost parts of the sea; in the most distant
> isles of it, in the farthest parts of the world, the sea being
> supposed the boundary of it: or "in the uttermost parts of the west"
> F7, as opposed to the morning light and rising sun, which appear in
> the east; and the sea is often in Scripture put for the west, the
> Mediterranean sea being to the west of the land of Palestine; and
> could he go from east to west in a moment, as the above writer
> observes, there would God be. The Heathens represent Jupiter, their
> supreme god, as having three eyes, because he reigns in heaven, and in
> earth, and under the earth F8.

and and some commentaries in  https://biblehub.com/psalms/139-9.htm

> Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers (9) If . . .--Literally,
>
> I lift wings of dawn
>
> I dwell in the end of the sea.
>
> The wings of the morning.--This exquisite image suggesting not only
> **the pinions of cloud that seem often to lift the dawn into the sky,** but also the swift sailing of the light across the world, may
> be compared to the "wings of the sun" in Malachi 4:2, and the "wings
> of the wind" in Psalm 18:10.
>
> The uttermost parts of the sea--i.e., to a Hebrew the extreme west.
> The poet imagines himself darting from east to farthest west, with the
> rapidity of light.

Therefore, based on said commentaries, one way of interpreting phrase in Psalm 139:9 "the wings of the dawn/the wings of the morning" is the sunlight rays furthest distance from the sun ( on the edge of the picture below which is marked by the oval shapes )

[image]

Comment: Very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

#### What does phrase in Psalm 139:9 "the wings of the dawn/the wings of the morning" mean?

The article "[Jehovah Knows Us Well!](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1990045#h=15)" in the *Watchtower* January 15, 1990 issue provides the meaning for the phrase:

> These words are poetically descriptive of how the light of dawn, as if having wings, quickly spreads from the east to the west. But what if David could take the wings of the dawn and reach the most distant sea or islands in the west? He would still be subject to God’s hand, or control and direction. By means of His spirit, Jehovah would be there to guide the psalmist compassionately.​—[Psalm 51:11](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1990045/24/0).

This is just another example of how Jehovah God gave David, and all of us, the ability to express ourselves in a way that magnifies our Creator.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 0):

I'm just putting a perspective here! So could it mean "having a fresh wing" there by he could go even to the end of the sea with out tiring or slowing?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/43457)